# Are Defences that have been purchased but not yet started to build added to war weight

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I purchase inferno towers but do not start to build them, will they add to my bases war weight?

Comment: Can you clarify? How can you purchase something but not build them?

Comment: Do you mean : "Am I able to use my inferno towers in clan wars while they are being built?" ?

Answer (score 1):

Your can't buy something without building it. At least not with the most recent version of the app. I'm guessing war weight is how much stuff you have, for percentages in attacks. I do believe it is added to your warrival weight, but is quite easy to destroy while it's being upgraded.

Comment: when you start building a defense it is immediately usable as a lvl 1 defense in your war base, in a war base nothing is ever being upgraded.
That being said, it is best to start building it AFTER the clan war matchmaking is done, so your newly started upgrade doesn't affect the war weight for this war.

Answer (score 0):

No, unplaced buildings do not contribute to war weight. One of my friends in my clan has a level 2 unplaced inferno and very similar level defenses to another member in the clan who only has 1 level 1 inferno, and is ranked lower than the member with one placed inferno. So buying something without placing it will not increase the war weight of your base.

Comment: how do you buy something without placing it?

Comment: @ThomasMulder, if you buy it from the store in a pack, you don't have to place it.